# Unable to load the account list, reload and try again

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

When visiting https://app.google.stackdriver.com I am presented with the error `Unable to load the account list, reload and try again.`, then after ca. 2 seconds I'm redirected to the Stackdriver logo and a link `Log in with Google`. After clicking that and selecting my account, I am redirected to the beginning of this problem again.

When going to https://console.cloud.google.com and selecting Stackdriver in *different* projects, I am sent through erroneous the process.

Comment: It could be cached credentials that are no longer being valid. Have you tried to clear the cache, use an incognito browser session, or trying a different browser?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, have tried incognito, also switching off all extensions.

Comment: If you also tried from a different network and a different device, I advise that you report it on [issuetracker](http://issuetracker.google.com/) for an investigation. Be ready to supply your project information, a redacted [HAR](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer/) file, and a [netlog](https://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/providing-network-details) trace once you get a response (not before that as it could be visible to the public).

Comment: Use safari or mozilla. This issue is in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was solved by support after filing a bug with the details. The specifics of the problem weren't communicated.